# Necessity for the equality of two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $R$, $S$, and $T$ be subspaces of a vector space.
I was able to show that $(R \cap T)+(S \cap T) \subseteq (R+S) \cap T$.

So my  question now is:
When will equality happen without using the other inclusion?

Comment: What does "without using the other inclusion" exactly mean?

Comment: Since it was established that $(R \cap T)+(S \cap T) \subseteq (R+S) \cap T$. I mean not to use this inclusion  $(R \cap T)+(S \cap T) \supseteq (R+S) \cap T$ to establish the equality. In other words, what should be the sufficient hypothesis for it to be equal. Thanks.

Comment: If your vector space is a finite dimensional vector space with an inner product, the two sides are the same.